# How to find a value in a nested array and merge it with a value from a higher array level?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have been trying for some time to find the currently active filter `OptionCode` and merge it together with the `FilterCode` into a new object. The `OptionCode` is deeper nested in the Array than the `FilterCode`.

```
filters = [
      {
        FilterCode: "TourPrice", // Take that filter code
        FilterName: "Tour Price",
        Options: [
          { Name: "Free", OptionCode: "Free", active: false, blocked: false },
          { Name: "Paid", OptionCode: "Paid", active: false, blocked: false },
          {
            Name: "Free and Paid",
            OptionCode: "FreeAndPaid", // take that Option Code
            active: true, //<- active
            blocked: false,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        FilterCode: "SortedBy", // Take that filter code
        FilterName: "Sorted By",
        Options: [
          {
            Name: "Most Relevant",
            OptionCode: "MostRelevant",// Take that OptionCode Here
            active: true, // <- active  
            blocked: false,
          },
          {
            Name: "Latest Tour",
            OptionCode: "LatestTour",
            active: false,
            blocked: false,
          },
          {
            Name: "Oldest Tour",
            OptionCode: "OldestTour",
            active: false,
            blocked: false,
          },
          {
            Name: "Lowest Price",
            OptionCode: "LowestPrice",
            active: false,
            blocked: false,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
```

The result should look like that `const activeFilters = {TourPrice: "FreeAndPaid", SortedBy: "MostRelevant" }`. The first value is the `FilterCode` the second the currently active `OptionCode`. Only one option  is active at a time per filter (i.e. never zero or never more than one options can be active).

Comment: Will there only ever be at most one active Option?

Comment: Yes there will always be a maximum of only one active option. I.e. there is always one Option selected never less and never more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on your `filter` array to create an array of `[key, value]` pairs. The key here is the `FilterCode` from each object, and the `value` here is the Name property from the object obtained by calling [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on your Options array, and finding the object with an `active` property set to `true`. You can then wrap this array of key-value pairs into a call to [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to build your object:

```js
const filters = [{ FilterCode: "TourPrice", FilterName: "Tour Price", Options: [{ Name: "Free", OptionCode: "Free", active: false, blocked: false }, { Name: "Paid", OptionCode: "Paid", active: false, blocked: false }, { Name: "Free and Paid", OptionCode: "FreeAndPaid", active: true, blocked: false, }, ], }, { FilterCode: "SortedBy", FilterName: "Sorted By", Options: [{ Name: "Most Relevant", OptionCode: "MostRelevant", active: true, blocked: false, }, { Name: "Latest Tour", OptionCode: "LatestTour", active: false, blocked: false, }, { Name: "Oldest Tour", OptionCode: "OldestTour", active: false, blocked: false, }, { Name: "Lowest Price", OptionCode: "LowestPrice", active: false, blocked: false, }, ], }, ];

const res = Object.fromEntries(filters.map(({FilterCode, Options}) => [
  FilterCode, Options.find(obj => obj.active).Name
]));
console.log(res);
```